# Calculating euler angles from DCM matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently interested in rotation topic, and i stumbled upon a little problem.
In example i have Rzyz DCM matrix with radians. And based on that i want to calculate zyz euler angles.

The problem is that, on some sources i see that equations are different, and don't have a clue why is that.

In example to calculate zyz angles on one source, it gives:
Rz = arctan2(R23, -R13)
Ry = arccos(R33)
Rz = arctan2(R32,R31)

On another source:
Rz = arctan2(R32, R31)
Ry = arccos(R33)
Rz = arctan(R23, -R13)

Does it depend if we are using active or passive rotation? (active -> vector rotates ; passive -> frame rotates).

Thanks a lot for any input on the topic

Comment: What is a "Rzyz DCM" matrix ?

Comment: By ZYZ i meant rotation order in rotation matrix. 
DCM - direction cosine matrix